# Find $\int \frac{1}{x^n(x-a)}dx$

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{x^n(x-a)}dx$.

Do I split into partial fractions or do integration by parts?

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\dfrac a{x^n(x-a)}=\dfrac{x-(x-a)}{x^n(x-a)}=\dfrac1{x^{n-1}(x-a)}-\dfrac1{x^n}$$

So if $\int\dfrac{dx}{x^n(x-a)}=I_n,$

$$aI_n=I_{n-1}-\int\dfrac{dx}{x^n}$$

Comment: How can you be so fast (moreover with good answers !!) ?? Cheers